# Using PHP with a MySQL db, how can I select everything from a row if i dont know what the columns are?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table but I dont know what the columns are except for 1 column. There is only 1 permanent data value for each row, the rest of the columns are added and removed elsewhere. This isnt a problem for the query, i just do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

but for the php function bind_result() i need to give it variables for each column, which i do not know.

I think that once I have the columns in an array, I can do anther query and use call_user_func_array to bind the result to the array.

This seems like it would come up a lot so im wondering is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    foreach ($row as $field => $value)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
show columns from table;
```

And then parse that string to grab your column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `describe` command, which is used to list all of the fields in a table and the data format of each field. Usage:

```
describe TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$metadata = $prep_statement->result_metadata()
```

after you executed the statement and then loop through all result fields using something like

```
while( $field = $metadata->fetch_field() ) { }
```

the properties of $field are documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php